# ASP Configuration Error in <authentication mode="Windows" />

Tags: .net

I get that error when trying to "view in browser" from an aspx file in Visual Studio 2008.  The complication to the problem is that I'm not actually on the server itself, its a project that's been checked out from source control onto my local machine.  I've seen the solution for the problem if I were on the server but my computer is not and has not been configured to run as a server.  So is there some way to fix this without setting up my own computer as a server?  I'm pretty new to Visual Studio and the .net framework so if I've left something vital out or anything please just ask for clarification.

Thanks in advance!

--edit--

Thanks for the responses guys but the proposed solution won't work since the project is a 'web site' not a 'web project' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28VS.80%29.aspx#wapp_topic5

So I don't have a project file (.csproj) I can right click on to get the properties tab you're talking about.  Any more ideas for this problem considering these new facts?

Comment: What OS are you running on your development machine?  Is your machine in a domain or in a workgroup?

Comment: I never had a problem with this, what OS are you on? Is the project running on Cassini (Vis studio) or a local IIS?

Comment: Why do you think the solution only applies to servers? The Windows authentication mode is available on all Windows platforms, and the app-root requirement is too.

Comment: Jeff, I'm running on Windows Vista Ultimate and my machine is in a workgroup.  Henk, I'm not sure I follow our question.  I have no idea what the deployment version of the project is running off of, but I'm working on my local copy in Visual Studio.  It's definitely not running off a local IIS since that isn't currently enabled on my machine.  Tor, if that is the case I haven't been able to figure it out.  The first step of the solution is to run IIS manager and when I type 'inetmgr' into run (or search) as per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770472%28WS.10%29.aspx it is not found

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the website project properties, go to the Web tab.  Under the Servers, there are a couple options.  I usually use the default which is "Use Visual Studio Development Server" and "Auto Assign Port".

If this website has been migrated from an earlier version of VS, it might not be set up to run that way (spec. 1.1 used the IIS server locally). If you want to use the IIS server, you will need to run it and config the virtual dir for it.

Comment: This sounds like exactly the solution I'm looking for but I cannot find 'website project properties'.  Should I have the project open, closed?  Is it in the solutions explorer, the main menu?  Sorry, like I said I'm new to Visual Studio and the thing is enormous!

Comment: I'd agree that this is the problem.  To make the changes, have the project open in Visual Studio, right click the project in the Project Explorer and select Properties.

Comment: I don't seem to have these options.  When I have the project open and right click on it I have the option for 'Property Pages' but not 'Properties'.  When I go to Property Pages I have the tab options of 'References', 'Build', 'Accessibility', 'Start Options', and 'MSBuild Options'. Under the Start Options there is a section labeled 'Server' and there is a radio button marked that says 'Use default web server' but there's no port option or Use Visual Studio Development Server.  This is a project I've checked out from source control, not created myself.

Comment: Perhaps that has something to do with it?  Also when I first ran Visual Studio I chose the web development mode.  The version (copied straight from the about) is Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: The property pages is a similar thing - I get it on a website that is running under 2005.  I use the Default Server setting with windows authentication.  I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the cause of many issues .. even XML issues in the web.config above this XML node in the web.config.. perhaps a XML closing "/" on an XML node..

I recently got this error because of a Telerik Rad Controls for ASP.NET AJAX upgrade.  The Upgrade Wizard from the Telerik Visual Studio menu automatically converted some settings in my web.config file.  It also added some things it shouldn't have.  After removing this XML node altogether, it fixed this issue.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```